# Passing arguments by reference in curried arguments

Tags: f#

I'm attempting to implement the interface `IDispatchMessageInspector` (of WCF fame) in F#:

```
open System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher
open System.ServiceModel.Channels

type ServiceInterceptor() as interceptor = 

    abstract member PreInvoke : byref<Message> -> obj
    abstract member PostInvoke : byref<Message> -> obj -> unit

    default x.PreInvoke m = null
    default x.PostInvoke m s = ()

    interface IDispatchMessageInspector with
         member x.AfterReceiveRequest(request, channel, instanceContext) = interceptor.PreInvoke(&request)
         member x.BeforeSendReply(reply : byref<Message>, correlationState) = interceptor.PostInvoke &reply correlationState
```

This fails to compile with the following error:

[image]

However, if I modify my code to the following (note the change of signature in `PostInvoke`) everything works:

```
open System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher
open System.ServiceModel.Channels

type ServiceInterceptor() as interceptor = 

    abstract member PreInvoke : byref<Message> -> obj
    abstract member PostInvoke : byref<Message> * obj -> unit

    default x.PreInvoke m = null
    default x.PostInvoke (m, s) = ()

    interface IDispatchMessageInspector with
         member x.AfterReceiveRequest(request, channel, instanceContext) = interceptor.PreInvoke(&request)
         member x.BeforeSendReply(reply : byref<Message>, correlationState) = interceptor.PostInvoke(&reply, correlationState)
```

Is this behaviour expected?  And if so could someone explain the reasoning behind it....

Comment: Not sure it'll help ; when experimenting, I tried using `(ref arg)` instead of using `&arg` and I got that error : *error FS0440: Methods with curried arguments cannot declare (...) or 'byref' arguments* So it's probably expected behaviour ; for the why now I have no clue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that `byref<'T>` is not a real type in .NET. F# uses this for representing values that are passed via `ref` and `out` parameters, but it is not a normal type that could appear anywhere in your program.

F# restricts the scope in which they can be used - you can only use them for local variables (basically passing around a reference or a pointer) and you can use them as method parameters (where the compiler can then compile it as a method parameter).

With curried methods, the compiler is producing a property that returns a function value and so (under the cover), you get something like a property `PostInvoke` of type `FSharpFunc<T1, FSharpFunc<T2, T3>>`. And here, `T1` or `T2` cannot be `byref<T>` types, because `byref` is not a real .NET type. So that's why curried methods cannot have `byref` parameters.

Another case where you can see this is if you, for example, try to create a list of `byref` values:

```
let foo () =
  let a : list<byref<int>> = []
  a
```

Here you get:

> error FS0412: A type instantiation involves a byref type. This is not permitted by the rules of Common IL.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Tomas - the observation that `byref<'T>` is not a type suddenly makes it clear - thank you!

Comment: It's perhaps worth saying that even the exception message does not recognise your observation: ".. but here has type `byref<'a>`..."!

Comment: Yeah, I think the F# compiler treats it as a type during type checking, but then erases it during code generation - so it is a fake type :) (in a way `System.Void` behaves similarly... it looks like a type, but you can't create a list of voids...)